# Generate n artificial points in given n-dimensional space, but no point should be present in original space in R

Tags: r, matrix, random, uniform

I want to generate `n artificial points` with uniform distribution in a given n-dimensional `Original_space`, but `no artificial point` should be present in the `Original_space`.

`EDIT`:
Each `row` above is a `point`, we need to generate `new rows` or `artificial points` that are not in `original space`

Example:

```
> Original_space = matrix(sample(runif(10,0,1), 9*100, TRUE),4,6)
> Original_space
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.9353045 0.65987073 0.12301011 0.6598707 0.01346191 0.4676935
[2,] 0.1230101 0.01346191 0.46769352 0.6598707 0.01346191 0.6660970
[3,] 0.3539783 0.66609697 0.67533240 0.6753324 0.46769352 0.9353045
[4,] 0.9076819 0.90768191 0.05189017 0.6660970 0.46769352 0.4676935
```

new `n-artificial points` should be generated `uniformly` in the above space, but none should be an exact match to the above space.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "artificial points"? otherwise it is tough to understand what would constitute an answer.

Comment: Each `row` above is a point, we need to generate new `rows` or `artificial points` that are not in original space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt:

```
my_fun <- function(matrix, n){
    out <- apply(matrix, 2, function(x){
      minx = min(x)
      maxx = max(x)
      repeat{
        z <- runif(n, min = minx, max = maxx)
        b <- sum(z %in% x)
        if(b == 0){
          break}
      }
      return(z)
    }
    )
    return(out)
}
```

usage:

```
set.seed(1)
Original_space <- matrix(sample(runif(10,0,1), 9*100, TRUE),4,6)
Original_space
#output
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.5728534 0.66079779 0.90820779 0.9446753 0.2655087 0.2016819
[2,] 0.3721239 0.20168193 0.66079779 0.3721239 0.9082078 0.8983897
[3,] 0.9446753 0.66079779 0.06178627 0.5728534 0.6291140 0.2016819
[4,] 0.9082078 0.06178627 0.57285336 0.9082078 0.9082078 0.3721239

my_fun(Original_space, 5)
#output
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.7601605 0.5771100 0.78008265 0.7743456 0.7774027 0.7951922
[2,] 0.4930669 0.4834536 0.43715634 0.4042942 0.7109603 0.2648927
[3,] 0.5947576 0.3569482 0.90182360 0.3905363 0.5210135 0.4814798
[4,] 0.5799297 0.6500261 0.09738581 0.9274622 0.6986689 0.6812729
[5,] 0.7703199 0.3554926 0.64491254 0.7627202 0.7822417 0.8430472
```

How it works:

arguments are the starting matrix (`matrix`) and the number of points (`n`) to be generated

For each column `apply(matrix, 2, function(x)`
get the min and max `minx = min(x)` and `maxx = max(x)`
repeat: `z <- runif(n, min = minx, max = maxx)`
until no elements in z are in the appropriate column and then return `z`

Do note that this is a more stringent criteria than requested, since I assume no coordinate should match for a given point while your criteria is that all coordinates should not match - if that is requested you can safely remove the repeat loop since chances of all coordinates matching are quite slim.